# CruiseControl: Changed detected, but timestamps in Working Copy unchanged

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol, dashboard, build.xml

Having fun and games with CruiseControl.

I have rigged up a Java project to a local install of CruiseControl on my windows XP machine.

My config.xml file runs every minute, and builds my project from my ant script.

Despite detecting changes to the Trunk in my "Modifications" tab in the Dashboard, when I look at the date and timestamps of the affected files in my Working Copy, I notice that these are unchanged.

It is this local copy which my build.xml runs against, so I am worried that, whilst my config.xml is configured correctly such that CruiseControl detects a change, my Ant script is not running against a Working Copy which is synchronised with the Trunk.

I post my configuration files with the hope that someone out there spots something that's obvious to them, but not to me!

Config xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cruisecontrol>

    <dashboard url="http://localhost:8080/dashboard" postinterval="1" />

    <project name="myProject" requireModification="false">
        <listeners>
                <currentbuildstatuslistener file="logs/myProject/status.txt"/>
            </listeners>

            <bootstrappers>
            <svnbootstrapper file="build.xml" 
            username="cruise_control" password="password" 
                localWorkingCopy="projects\myProject" />
        </bootstrappers>

        <modificationset>
            <svn repositoryLocation="https://path/to/myTrunk" 
                localWorkingCopy="projects/myProject"
                 username="cruise_control" password="password">
                </svn>
            </modificationset>

            <schedule interval="60" >
            <ant buildfile="build.xml" anthome="C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.8.2" antWorkingDir="projects/myProject/" />
            </schedule>

        <log>
                <merge dir="C:\Program Files\CruiseControl\projects\myProject\reports\junit" pattern="TEST*.xml" />
        </log> 

        <publishers>
            <artifactspublisher dir="C:\Program Files\CruiseControl\projects\myProject\dist"
                dest="C:\Program Files\CruiseControl\artifacts\myProject"
                moveInsteadOfCopy="true"  />
        </publishers>   
    </project>
</cruisecontrol>
```

Dashboard config file:

```
 <dashboard>
    <buildloop
        logsdir="C:/Program Files/CruiseControl/logs/"
        artifactsdir="C:/Program Files/CruiseControl/artifacts/" />
    <features allowforcebuild="true" />
    <trackingtool projectname="" baseurl="" keywords=""/>
    <subtabs>
        <subtab class="net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.dashboard.widgets.ErrorsAndWarningsMessagesWidget" />
    </subtabs>
</dashboard>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I configured the sameway as Ben pointed out above. However, I ran into two issues.

1. If I don't have a local working copy the very "first time" around, the SVNBootsTrapper does NOT update my local working directory. I've to either do an explicit "svn checkout" from command line or via ant script or manually move the code into this local working directory. After that the "SVN Boots Trapper" can update my local working dir/copy with repository changes. Is this how the SVNBoots trapper works OR is this the approach we've to take for first time repository to local working copy population?

2.I only had

```
<bootstrappers>
    <svnbootstrapper file="build.xml" localWorkingCopy="projects\myProject" />
</bootstrappers>
```

and no uid/pwd field. In my old Cruisecontrol prior to 2.8.4 version, it would work fine. But here it fails and asks me:

ProjectController - 'myProject' Controller: build progress event: bootstrapping
SVNBootstrapper  - svn: Can't get password

And it fails. The only way around this password problem is:

a. Either add the attributes username and password (as Ben has above) OR

b. Run a cmd line svn update command, provide uid/pwd when prompted. And then say yes to store your password  'unencrypted'. 
Is there a way around to using both approaches (a) and (b) to my second issue?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC `Cruisecontrol` detects changes to repository, but does not update the working copy automatically. So one possibility is that your build script does not have the code to update the working copy with the changes in the repository (i.e. do an `svn update`).

Comment: You are correct Raghuram. SVNBootStrapper is responsible for SVN update. I had not configured this task correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

My bootstrapper was as follows:

```
<svnbootstrapper file="build.xml" 
            username="cruise_control" password="password" 
                localWorkingCopy="projects\myProject" />
```

With the "file" property, svnbootsraper only monitors the given file.

When this property is removed, the bootstrapper monitors the whole working copy:

```
<svnbootstrapper username="cruise_control" password="password" 
                localWorkingCopy="projects\myProject" />
```

It would appear to be a common mistake for one to assume that the modificationset attribute performs an SVN update. In fact, it only listens for increments to the Revision Number. Is the svnbootstrapper that performs the SVN update.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Actually svnbootstrapper (http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html#svnbootstrapper) is meant to update a single file (typically build.xml), which in turn should run an svn update task. What you have suggested may work, but is probably not correct.

Comment: The "correct" way would be to let the ant script do the actual svn update command. Also note that the modificationset will ignore the localWorkingCopy as it already has a repositoryLocation and using both is not supported.